# SQL Server stops regularly on every windows restart

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

**Edit 3 & 4 Added**

Although the SQL Server instance is **set to run automatically** and TCP also is enabled in  its Network Configuration, the SQL Server is **stopped** after each system restart. I have to go into the configuration and start it again manually.

**Edit :**
It's default account is `"Network Service"`

What is the cause of this, and what solutions are available?

**Edit 5 - Repost**

***The Event Log :***

Repost

http://pastebin.com/fdktP3mP

**Edit 4 :** (Expired Link)

Here is the **Last** Error Log of today

http://pastebin.com/hLyVHZud

**Edit3 : - Part 2/2**

Seems that this error doesn't appear on every start
cause It's started after my last restart, the time that I wanted to
clear and refresh the Logs and probing the error :D

I think in the Event Log as other experts mentioned there are good informative points
and I hope we could find the real problem
e.g some errors are saying `Network Service` couldn't login ...
but after a minute or so it seems that It logged on !

Comment: How is the SQL Server service configured?

Comment: What does the event log say? (Also, this should really be on Database Administrators SE http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I'll check the Event Log , I posted about it's configuration, What else should I say ?

Comment: @Shark , this could be the way I should observe similar errors but unfortunately I'm not accustomed to the Event Logs, Where Should I check windows Event viewer ?

Comment: @Oded if any other info should I provide please tell me

Comment: are you switch and nics set to the same settings as in auto\auto  if not the network might not be coming up fast enough.

Comment: switch and nics ?? In the Configuration Manager "Sql Server" was set to run automatically

Comment: We also need the windows system eventlog from the point the sql service starts up.

Comment: @tony How can I get and extract the part you need from Event log

Comment: open up a powershell prompt and run "get-eventlog -log system -after "3/8/2012 9:56:05 PM"  -before "3/8/2012 10:56:05 PM""  setting the after and before to the times surrounding the problem.

Comment: also get-eventlog -log application -after "3/8/2012 9:56:05 PM"  -before "3/8/2012 10:56:05 PM"

Comment: I wasn't on my computer for hours ...

Comment: @tony the powershell command seems to do nothing and doesn't show me anything, is the result stored somewhere ?? or it really didn;t take effect ?

Comment: I'm trying to gather the needed information for resolving this issue

Comment: Everyone wanted the Event Log, After posting it, seems no one is interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a named instance, that I'm guessing was setup to support another piece of software.  Check the dependencies of the SQL Server service and see if it's dependent on another service which isn't being started for some reason.

Comment: I'm trying to get it's Event Log, As I remember it wasn't related to Some other Server programs such as sharepoint, in my previous installations of Sql Server I never experienced this, I think in this setup I added some credentials with granted permissions for ease of access, further than that I couldn't remember anything to be dependant, e.g could it be dependant to sa Account ?? shoul agent be run this way ?

Comment: Look in the services applet in Admin tools to see if the MSSQL$PROSERVER service is dependent on any other drivers or services.  If the service isn't starting there should be something listed in the Application or System log which says why the service wasn't started or why it failed.  If the service isn't starting odds are there won't be anything in the SQL ERRORLOG file.  The SQL Instance isn't dependent on the sa account.

Comment: No Sir, It's not dependent to anything, Just as expected sa is dependent to it nothing else, Now I can see a weird change, It's started automatically ! I'll add a piece of info to my first post

Comment: Can you repost the errorlog info? The links aren't working.

Comment: Reposted the Event Log : http://pastebin.com/fdktP3mP

Comment: What's the default database for the login "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"?

Comment: The Database is "master"

Comment: In addition seems that there are 2 "Network Service" and "sa" accounts : one is "NT SERVICE\MSSQL$PROSERVER", the other "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE", it wasn't something I decide, maybe that happened during installation unintentionally is it good ? or could it be the cause of some errors ?

Comment: Sounds like something is just trying to log into the database and failing.  Maybe some service that is configured to connect but the database has been removed.  This doesn't have anything to do with your problem of the SQL Server not starting.

Comment: As the SQL Server isn't starting the answer won't be in the SQL Server's ERRORLOG.  What's in the system event log after the restart?

Comment: This is an old question here, so after getting a new answer, decided to mark your answer as the answer cause of the volume of participation.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you have storage that is coming online after the SQL Server starts?  For instance, if your master database is on SAN storage that is not being attached to the server until after SQL Server tries to start up.  This will cause SQL Server to appear in a Stopped state after a restart, but work when you manually start it.  You can create a dependency for the SQL Server service to prevent this.

Do you have a copy of the error log AFTER the start up?  The one you provided appears that it is after you manually started it and then had it shutdown.

Comment: master seems to be on local from the sql logs.

Comment: Thanks for your response, sorry being late at that time I couldn't give the needed reply, Now everything seems up-to-time and accurate, If any other info is needed I'll provide, the SQL Server is in local as said, thanks in advance

Comment: Looking at your last error log - it says that NetworkService is unable to open a specified database. Your service account should have master set as it's default database. I am wondering if it is set to a different database that has not yet gone through startup recovery some of the time.  Ensure the default database is master.

Comment: @Brian sorry Mr.Brian I didn't see your comment, maybe no notification, anyway yes it's "master", seems that the result happens not every time. any suggestions ?

Comment: In addition seems that there are 2 "Network Service" and "sa" accounts : one is "NT SERVICE\MSSQL$PROSERVER", the other "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE", it wasn't something I decide, maybe that happened during installation unintentionally is it good ? or could it be the cause of some errors ?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is losing logon details and therefore not being able to start the server.
Perform the steps below:

1. Go to SQL Configuration Manager
2. Open with "Run as administrator"
3. Make sure start mode is set to automatic
4. Right click on SQL server instance and set the log on properties like this:
   [image]

and that's it !!

Comment: Hello, thanks for trying to participate on answering this question, this issue was too old, I changed PCs, OSs and SQLSMS versions.